# Maven 3.0.2 - WAR File is duplicating dependant JARS in two places

Tags: maven

When I run: "mvn package -skipTests" from the command line to create my WAR file, Maven copies my dependent jars into WEB-INF/lib, and then copies them again into the root of the WAR.  So I end up with the same files in two different places.  I've stripped my pom.xml down to the bare essentials, but the duplicates still occur.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>webproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WebProject</name>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>               

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/config/env/dev/application.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/jdbc.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/config/env/dev/jdbc.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/jdbc.properties" />
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sun</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.beans
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.aop
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context.support
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.jdbc
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.web
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.orm
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.test
            </artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations
            </artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager
            </artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're not using Maven 3.0.3, which is the latest version? I'm not saying this would solve your problem, though.

Comment: Somehow the jars were all copied into my target output directory and they were getting copied into the WAR.  I cleaned the target path and the problem went away.

Comment: In general you want to always do a `clean` when you invoke `mvn package/install/deploy`